# Why is my VHDL clock signal so far off from what I thought it would be?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, frequency, clock

I'm new to FPGA and VHDL.  The following code was supposed to be `5MHz` but I'm getting `4.167MHz` on my scope.

The FPGA board I have is a `Mojo v3` that has a `50MHz` clock.

What am I doing wrong?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity clock is
    port (
        clk_50mhz   : in    std_logic;
        rst         : in    std_logic;
        clk_out     : out   std_logic
    );
end clock;

architecture Behavioral of clock is
    signal prescaler    : unsigned(4 downto 0);
    signal clk_out_i    : std_logic;
begin
    gen_clk : process(clk_50mhz, rst)
    begin -- process gen_clk
        if rst = '1' then
            clk_out_i   <= '0';
            prescaler   <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clk_50mhz) then   -- rising clock edge
            if prescaler = X"5" then        -- (50_000_000 / 5_000_000) / 2
                prescaler   <= (others => '0');
                clk_out_i   <= not clk_out_i;
            else
                prescaler   <= prescaler + "1";
            end if;
        end if;
    end process gen_clk;

    clk_out <= clk_out_i;

end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

50MHz/4.16666MHz = 12.

You are counting to 6 twice, not 5 twice as you think you are.
The classic off-by-one error :)

If it seems muddled, try simulating your code, and that ought to clear things up.

Comment: +1. It's very easy to forget that the counter starts at 0, so if you count up to 5 then reset, you are doing 0-1-2-3-4-5-0 which is 6 clock cycles.

Comment: Agreed. Also called a fence-post error. If you need 20 yards of fencing with posts every 2 yards, how many posts do you need? (Hint: 20 divided by 2 equals 10, but that's not the answer,)

Comment: That was it!   DUR!!!  It's now `5.000MHz`!  Thanks.